# Javascript converting string to number and formatting

Tags: javascript

So I'm getting this string '41803.96000000'

what i want to do is convert this to a number and it should be in the
right format such as this example '41.96000000'

for anyone wondering this is the current bitcoin price which I'm getting from a binance WebSocket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `parseFloat('41803.96000000')`

Comment: Sorry it is a typo (kinda)